# Difference between Hall subgroups and Sylow subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I'm reading about Hall subgroups in Robinson's book and I'm confused about two definitions (page 252).

Let $\pi$ be a nonempty set of primes.

**Def 1**. *A Sylow $\pi$-subgroup of $G$ is defined to be a maximal $\pi$-subgroup.*

**Def 2**. *If $G$ is a finite group a Hall $\pi$-subgroup is a $\pi$-subgroup $H$ such that $|G:H|$ is a $\pi'$-number (or $\gcd(|H|,|G:H|) = 1$)*.

He says that is obvious (and I agree) that every Hall $\pi$-subgroup if a Sylow $\pi$-subgroup. But I cannot see why the converse is not true, at least in finite case.

For example, in this page he says that a $\pi$-subgroup always exists but Hall subgroup not always. He says that a $\{3,5\}$-subgroup of $A_5$ not exists (I think this can be done using group actions), but $60 = 3\cdot 5 \cdot 2^2$ so that a Sylow $\{3,5\}$-subgroup (that is maximal), should not have order $15$ and index $4$?

Comment: Sylow subgroups are, by definition, $p$ groups. The only time a Hall subgroup is also a Sylow subgroup is wheb $\pi$ is a singleton set. On the other hand, any Sylow subgroup is necessarily a Hall subgroup. I think you've got things backwards. In particular, "Sylow $\{3,5\}$ subgroup" does not make any sense.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I knew the definition of Sylow subgroups just when $\pi$ is a singleton, but Robinson's wrotte the following sentence: "While Sylow $\pi$-subgroups always exist, they are usually not conjugate if $\pi$ contains more than one prime". Also, he uses the difference between singletons when write "Hall $p$-subgroup and Sylow $p$-subgroup are synonymous for finite groups". That things confused me.

Comment: A maximal $\pi$ subgroup need not be a Hall subgroup if the index is not a $\pi'$ number. $A_5$ certainly has $\{3,5\}$ subgroups (e.g., subgroups of order $3$ and $5$). The non-existence of a subgroup of order $15$ tells you they are maximal $\{3,5\}$ subgroups, but their indices are not powers of $2$, so they are not Hall $\{3,5\}$-subgroups.

Comment: Under the (in my experience mon-standard) terminology you have given, a subgroup of order $3$ of $A_5$ would be a Sylow $\{3,5\}$-subgroup, being maximal among $\{3,5\}$-subgroups. But not a Hall $\{3,5\}$-subgroup by index considerations.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so in that context, Sylow $\pi$-subgroup is just a maximal $\pi$-subgroup and in this case, need not have the maximal order possible and because of that, the index condition of Hall subgroup need not to be satisfied.

Comment: That is, literally, the definition you quoted...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I got it now. The terminology Sylow $\pi$-subgroups made me think in the maximal order so the confusion happens. Thank you.